Complicated site for users. Can this be simplified?
First time logging into this with everything you click on it leads you to another thing to login into or sign up to. It is unclear and not user-friendly. All I want to do is ask a simple question then it says you must go to stack overflow then you go to stack overflow and another dialog box pops up, asking you a bunch of additional questions. Whoever put this site together needs to simplify it.

Yeah, that's there cause people find it hard to ask good questions and need help to simplify the process

You seem to confuse this site with a personal helpdesk, but it isn't. It's made for research primarily. So your questions need to meet certain quality criteria, hence these additional dialog boxes, etc., these are made to help you writing good questions.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

The topic on how to make it easier for new users to navigate and use the site is brought up a lot here on Meta. I don't think we need another version of the question. | This question is similar to: Introducing new user onboarding project. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's not that complicated. You are asked to press 2 simple buttons and enter 3 small things in order to sign up (and then to press a button on an email). Presumably you want an answer to said simple question. That help box, if you actually read it, can help you avoid your question being closed/deleted without an answer. As well, it takes much longer to answer even a simple question (with some exceptions) than it takes to do the above. Frankly, it's taken me longer to write this answer and you longer to write this question than this whole process takes up.

I'm assuming you're referring to the question asking wizard/staging ground. It’s a Stack Overflow only feature that's meant to help new users find their way. Unlike many smaller sites, relying purely on community comments, and votes doesn’t entirely scale well for onboarding on SI.
Stack Exchange as a whole was initially designed to be very low friction for users. It was the same single question pane as you see here, you didn't need registration, and the differences you see there are a direct result of folks finding out some aspects didn't work well.
Some folks found that success in getting started in SO was too difficult, and they found the site unfriendly and hard to get used to.
The 'complexity' is meant to guide folks through their initial question asking experience and set them up for success in future - it breaks down your question into the discrete parts that folks expect from a question, lets you put in in a vaguely standard format, and critically, and hopefully, lets you get the question in a good place and sets you up to succeed.
I'm not sure if it is reputation-gated, but it is a tradeoff between "low friction" and "make sure people have all the help they need to post a good question" - and the latter is probably more helpful at this point of stack overflow's lifecycle. Improving curation and 'early' question asking hopefully leads to better questions and engagement.
As an old timer, I follow a very similar pattern in asking questions so, it is worth taking it in the spirit its in - it’s there to help you ask a better question and critically find the answer you need. It’s practically what you'd need to ask in a single text box anyway, just structured better.

"I'm not sure if its reputation gated" it depends, if you have less than 500 reputation I believe you need to have 2 "successful" questions to toggle the Ask Wizard off, if you have 500+ rep you can turn it off without having successful questions. Reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430524/14991864 (Note I might not be correct since the Ask Wizards criteria has been changed multiple times previously)

OP doesn't seem to have a Stack Overflow account, so I'm not sure they're referring to the Staging Ground at all. They seem to have come here from Home Improvement.

OP very much sounds like they're complaining about the ask question wizard.

I don't really know what OP refers to, because what they describe doesn't fit into any part of the UX. In particular, you're not asked to login then asked to login again. Well, unless you jump to different sites but that also raises the question what's the initial place you were - maybe stackexchange.com? The next part is something pointing you to Stack Overflow and I don't think such a thing exists. Might be a comment? The dialog box with additional questions might be the wizard. But you do get a popup the first time you ask even without the wizard.
